# replacing space with new line characters for vagrant box use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, sed, awk

I am trying to setup vagrant box using shell script where in I am storing `key` and `cert` files. Normal format of any cert or key file is as below

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIJAP384f0KeRndMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNV
....
0+ZQ+Yxjzs69VHdPJbzu3cxjNQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQC6qoE3hNniDqD7
....
wr5wa+bGBgNzIBLS5j9F9Kul
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However when I check on vagrant box it looks like below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDzzCCAregAwIB ..... 69VHdPJbzu3cxjNQ== -----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhki  .... OB7jnwaqq wr5wa+bGBgNzIBLS5j9F9Kul -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(basically, everything in one row)

Due to which Apache2 has errors in the log. Now I want to convert these keys to their proper format. I did try below

```
cat server.crt | tr " " "\n" 
cat server.crt | tr "\ /" " "
```

but it didn't help.

```
    -----BEGIN
CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIJAP384f0KeRndMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNV

0+ZQ+Yxjzs69VHdPJbzu3cxjNQ==
-----END
CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is what I am getting as a result of `sed -i 's/ /\n/g' *.crt` command. after END it goes to next line due to space character. 
Objective here is keep the first and last line as it is and format the content between them.

Comment: I really hope that you didn't copy the real private key over here. If you did, revoke the old certificate and renew certificate immediately.

Comment: No worries. I am using this for testing purpose.

Comment: Then  please make extra sure to not reuse this pair anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You want `sed -i 's/ /\n/g' *.crt` (assuming you have GNU sed)

But have you addressed the root cause? *How* did the files get corrupted?

Comment: I am sending the whole file as variable in shell script which is causing this change in file.

Comment: -----BEGIN
CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIJAP384f0KeRndMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMH4xCzAJBgNV
-----------------------------------------
0+ZQ+Yxjzs69VHdPJbzu3cxjNQ==
-----END
CERTIFICATE-----

This is what I am getting as a result of this command. after END it goes to next line due to space character.

Comment: Do you quote your `"$variable"` ?

Comment: You should read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tr '\ ' '\n'`

Example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 10 17:01:00 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a | tr '\ ' '\n'
Linux
localhost
2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
#1
SMP
Tue
Mar
10
17:01:00
EDT
2015
x86_64
x86_64
x86_64
GNU/Linux
```